# Columnwise removal of first ones from binary matrix. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, unique, binary-matrix

I have some binary matrix. I want to remove all first ones from each column, but keep `one` if this value is alone in column. I have some code, which produces correct result, but it looks ugly- I should iterate through all columns.

**Could You give me a piece of advice how to improve my code?**

Non-vectorised code:

```
% Dummy matrix for SE
M = 10^3;
N = 10^2;
ExampleMatrix = (rand(M,N)>0.9);
ExampleMatrix1=ExampleMatrix;
% Iterate columns
for iColumn = 1:size(ExampleMatrix,2)
    idx = find(ExampleMatrix(:,iColumn)); % all nonzeroes elements
    if numel(idx) > 1
        % remove all ones except first
        ExampleMatrix(idx(1),iColumn) = 0;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
ind_col = find(sum(ExampleMatrix, 1)>1); % index of relevant columns
[~, ind_row] = max(ExampleMatrix(:,ind_col), [], 1); % index of first max of each column
ExampleMatrix(ind_row + (ind_col-1)*size(ExampleMatrix,1)) = 0; % linear indexing
```

The code uses:

- the fact that the second output of [`max`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) gives the index of the *first* maximum value. In this case `max` is applied along the first dimension, to find the first maximum of each column;
- [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/).